# Have Android app send a random number to server

Tags: java, php, android

I need to send a random number from Android to a PHP script on my server every 5 seconds.  This is for a heart-rhythm simulator for learning purposes.  The data from the PHP file is then written to a database.  I have spent many hours searching for examples, but they have been hard to understand.  I need a simple example of how to do this.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Example of what? Generating the random number? sending it? receiving it? recording it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to send a string to a server and read a reply.
Just use Math.random() to generate the random number.

```
String ipAddy = "10.0.2.2 ";

        try {  
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddy, 1234);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(sockaddr);

            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                    //Issue some commands here!
                    out.println("Hey Server!");
                    out.flush();


                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String reversedString = in.readLine();                     
                    System.out.println(reversedString);

                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }finally{
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
                }
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```